# react native bundle is not taking environment variables provided from Jenkins

Tags: react-native, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job for building android from a react-native project. 
The pipeline script runs fine but when it reaches the `react-native-bundle` it fails telling me `couldn't find environment variable no .env present`.

Here is the script I use in jenkins

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
  stage("Checkout") {
      steps {
          echo "Environment: ${env.ENVIRONMENT}"
          checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/pipeline']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'p_rad', url: 'https://***.com/myprj.git']]]
      }
  }
  stage('Dependancies and Bundling') {
      steps {
          echo 'installing dependancies'
          nodejs('NodeJS_7.0.0') {
              sh label: '', script: 'npm install -g react-native-cli'
              sh label: '', script: 'npm install'
              sh label: '', script: 'npm run bundle-android-release'
              sh label: '', script: 'cd android'
              sh label: '', script: 'chmod +x gradlew'
              sh label: '', script: './gradlew clean assembleRelease'
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

the command `echo ${env.ENVIRONMENT}` prints dev as I am triggering a parameterized build from Jenkins and one parameter is ENVIRONMENT=dev

but react-native-bundle command couldn't take these values and error says no .env files under the specified location.

when I try `writeFile file: '.env', text: "some parameters=00"` the application is taking it(tried writing one parameter to .env file)

Comment: Where are you creating the .env file? There's nothing like this created out of the box for Jenkins AFAIK.

Comment: I am creating it in project root. My assumption was every variable in .env and the parameters from jenkins will go under process.env and then app will use them

. I managed to workaround by writing the environment variables to a file using writefile().